# Django authentication for multiple apps

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-3.x, django-models

I want to make two apps in my Django project - one for web pages (browser) and one for api calls (mobile app). Both apps should use same users for authentication.
So how should I implement it? I want to make one more app for users, but is it the right way to make app with just one model and without any other logic?

Comment: Django already has a built-in authentication framework, and it isn't restricted to a specific app.

Comment: I want to add some custom fields to it. As far as I know It can be done be creating one more model with relationship 1-to-1 with built-in user model. So I am talking about additional user model in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Custom User by extending the existing User model in Django. You can refer [Extending user Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can I use this custom user in multiple apps?